# Memory blocked out when using embedded Jetty as application server

Tags: java, memory, jetty

I am using embedded jetty as a Java application server, with maximum JVM memory set to 800MB.
I created a method to deploy and un-deploy web archives. Every time I deploy a war with a basic hello world application the embedded application server uses approximately 200MB additional memory which causes an out of memory after I add the 4th web app. Is this the expected behaviour for embedded Jetty when used as an application server?

```
@ManagedOperation
public boolean deployWebApp(String context, String pathToWar){
    boolean success = false;
    WebAppContext webctx = null;
    try{
        webctx = addWebApp(context, pathToWar);
        webctx.getTempDirectory();
        webctx.start();
        success = webctx.isRunning();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed to startup webapp with webappcontext: ", webapps.get(context).getContextPath());           
    }
    return success;     
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with jconsole and going through each of the handlers in the contexthandlercollection, it was discovered the undeployed webapps were not deleting the securityhandlers and sessionhandlers, as result the perm gen kept growing.

We programmatically deleted each of those handlers and we can see the perm gen memory reducing.

```
this.getSessionHandler().stop();
this.getSessionHandler().destroy();
this.getSecurityHandler().stop();
this.getSecurityHandler().destroy();
```

Answer (score 1):

No, I use embedded Jetty and it doesn't use anything like that amount of memory.

The best thing to do is create a heap dump and then use a tool like the Eclipse Memory Analyzer to analyse the heap and see what it is about the web apps that are consuming so much memory.

Comment: agreed, that should not be jetty doing that, also jetty has an overlay mechanism to reducing memory usage of multiple instances of the same war if that is what your shooting for: http://webtide.intalio.com/2011/05/jetty-overlayed-webapp-deployer/

Answer (score 0):

The undeploy/deploy memory leak could be related to various known JRE ClassLoader pinning issues.

We've recently (as of the past 2 days!) added some pre-emptive preventers of this pinning to the server side classloader to allow the WebAppClassLoader to operate in a way that doesn't leak references to the ClassLoader.

See: http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/jetty-util/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/util/preventers

These are all added to the server via the Server.addBean(Object) method.

You might have some luck using these on your embedded server.

Comment: You'll want to get yourself a memory profiler tool, capture the memory utilization and attempt to figure out where the utilization actually is.  (jetty, a 3rd party lib, the JRE, your app?)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716597/java-memory-leak-detection-tools

Comment: Thanks joakime, this matches my suspicions. I isolated the problem to the permgen memory causing OOM error. The permgen size does not decrease when an application gets undeployed making the embedded app server in effect a time bomb. Not sure how to address the issue other than restarting the JVM to load/unload war packages or using another JVM like JRockit that does not use permgen.

Comment: Currently we are using jetty-7.6.1.v20120215 and Oracle JVM version 1.6.0_26 with the following memory startup config;  
memory.opts=-XX:MaxPermSize=128m -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:MaxNewSize=256m -XX:NewSize=256m -Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:SurvivorRatio=128 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=0  -XX:+UseTLAB -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled